# Подсветка input при валидации формы

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как исправить условие так, чтобы `input`, прошедший валидацию, становился зелёным, а не прошедший — только красным?

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $('input#name-send, input#tel-send').unbind().blur( function(){

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();

    switch(id)
    {
        case 'name-send':
            var rv_name = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/; // используем регулярное выражение

            if(val.length >= 2 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val))
            {
                $("#name-send").addClass('not_error');
                $(this).removeClass('error')
            }
            else
            {
                $("#name-send").removeClass('not_error')
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }
            break;

        case 'tel-send':
            var rv_tel =  /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3,4}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{5,10}$/;
            console.log(id);
            if(val != '' && rv_tel.test(val))
            {
                $("#tel-send").addClass('not_error');
                $(this).removeClass('error')
            }
            else
            {
                $("#tel-send").removeClass('not_error')
                $(this).addClass('error');
            }
           break;   
       } // end switch(...)
     }); // end blur()


    $('form#feedback-form-send').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#name-send").val()=="" && $("#tel-send").val()==""){
            $("#name-send,#tel-send").css('border','2px solid red');
        }
        else if($('#name-send').hasClass('not_error')) {
            $("#name-send").css('border','2px solid green');
        }
        else if($('#name-send').hasClass('error')) {
            $("#name-send").css('border','2px solid red');
        }
        else if($('#tel-send').hasClass('not_error')) {
            $("#tel-send").css('border','2px solid green');
        }
        else if($('#tel-send').hasClass('error')) {
            $("#tel-send").css('border','2px solid red');
        }
        if($('.not_error').length == 2)
        {  
            $.ajax({
                url: 'controller/form.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){ 
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                },

                success: function(response){
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').removeAttr('disabled');  
                    alert(response);
                }
            }); 
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Какая-то у вас очень сложная конструкция и повторяющиеся проверки.

Попробуйте немного упростить код: вынесите оформление в css, проверку полей - в отдельную функцию, которую будете вызывать при необходимости. Если набросать примерно, то получится что-то вроде этого: https://jsfiddle.net/72466tro/2/

html:

```
<form id="feedback-form-send">
  <input type="text" id="tel-send">
  <input type="text" id="name-send">
  <input type="submit" value="GO!">
</form>
```

css:

```
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.not_error {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){       
    $('input#name-send, input#tel-send').blur( function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var val = $(this).val();
        reg_test(id,val);
});

    $('form#feedback-form-send').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var nameVal = $('#name-send').val(),
        telVal = $('#tel-send').val();
        reg_test('name-send', nameVal);
        reg_test('tel-send', telVal);
        if($('.not_error').length == 2) {  
            $.ajax({
                url: 'controller/form.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(xhr, textStatus){ 
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $('form#feedback-form-send :input').removeAttr('disabled');  
                    alert(response);
                }
            }); 
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
}); 
function reg_test(id, val) {
var $el = $('#' + id);
    switch(id) {
        case 'name-send':
            var rv_name = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$/;

            if(val.length >= 2 && val != '' && rv_name.test(val)) {
                $el.addClass('not_error');
                $el.removeClass('error')
            } else {
                $el.removeClass('not_error')
                $el.addClass('error');
            }
            break;
        case 'tel-send':
            var rv_tel =  /^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3,4}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{5,10}$/;
            if(val != '' && rv_tel.test(val)) {
                $el.addClass('not_error');
                $el.removeClass('error')
            } else {
                $("#tel-send").removeClass('not_error')
                $el.addClass('error');
            }
           break;   
       }
}
});
```

Comment: спасибо))......